# Is there an easy way to use vue.js or another javascript framework in Composite C1 framework?

Tags: .net, vue.js, c1-cms

i'm developing a big web site using Composite C1 CMS. And i'm wondering is there an easy way to add any modern javascript framework like vuejs? Now the biggest problem i see is that i need to have node.js on the server side working together with .Net. And by the way, i'm using Composite version 6.1.

Comment: I don't know your CMS, but the sure thing is that Vue doesen't require NodeJS to run. Vue is first of all a client-side library (while it can be server-rendered). You can perfectly serve Vue code as static assets with any backend technology.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I agree but how can i add it to project with minimum efforts? I mean should i write path to vueJs in web.config? For now the only way to use is, as i see, is add cdn-library to a correspondent page, and then refer to vueJs files, but with this approach i won't be able to use all the VueJS features. What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Its really very easy. Vue is the View of your MVC model, so yes it is completely possible to use Vue as it in a c1 CMS project but M and C will do most of the hard lifting.

Here are a few tutorial links that can solve your problem. I understand there is no direct guide for particular c1 cms but its 95% similar. Hope this helps.

https: //www.storyblok. com/tp/add-a-headless-CMS-to-vuejs-in-5-minutes

http://www.lambdatwist.com/dot-net-vuejs/

https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/02/14/running-vuejs-on-aspnet-core-apps/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the difficulty is that we already have a project and it's not .net core based. And by the way, Composite CMS is not .Net core based also. That means that server is giving back a layout, and that's the tricky part we cannot solve for now.